# Python Scraping, Sending 'Request Body' Data

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, httprequest

I just started learning Python and am by know means an expert. My area of expertise is in VBA.

When it comes to extracting data from the web, if you are doing so via VBA then winHttp is the best method. However, with VBA you're limited to single threading. One (kind of) way around this is using VBScript. While going the VBScript route would be the easiest way to do this as VBA and VBS are nearly identical, Python seems to be the best language when it comes to scraping from what I've read.

I have provided two examples below, one written in VBA (working) and an equivalent written in Python (not working).

**VBA**

```
Dim postData As String
Dim myHttp2 As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

'postData is the form data sent in the request body that contains a users login credentials

postData = "SMNC-ISO&LOC=US&target=HTTPS%3AIntranetSite.net&postpreservationdata=&USER=usr123&PASSWORD=pwd123"

set myHttp2 = CreateObject("winHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
myHttp2.Open "GET", "https://login.someintranetsite.net", true

myHttp2.setRequestHeader "Request", "GET /abcd123/4567 HTTP/1.1"
myHttp2.setRequestHeader "Accept", "stuff"
myHttp2.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US"
myHttp2.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "stuff"
myHttp2.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "stuff"
myHttp2.setRequestHeader "Host", "login.someintranetsite.net"

myHttp2.send postData
myHttp2.WaitForResponse

Debug.Print myHttp2.responseText

'obtains the session cookie needed for other requests not shown here
cookie = myHttp2.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
```

The above results in a valid response from the server.. however using Python...

**Python**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



payload = 'SMNC-ISO&LOC=US&target=HTTPS%3AIntranetSite.net&postpreservationdata=&USER=usr123&PASSWORD=pwd123'

headers = {'Request':   'GET /abcd123/4567 HTTP/1.1',
           'Accept' :  'stuff',
           'Accept-Language':  'en-US',
           'Connection':  'stuff',
           'Host':  'someintranetsite.net',
           'User-Agent': 'stuff',
           'Accept-Encoding':  'stuff'
           }

result = requests.get(url="https://login.someintranetsite.net", headers=headers, data=payload)

print result.content
```

When I attempt to run the above python  I get the below result:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 55, in get
return request('get', url, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 559, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 378, in send
raise ProxyError(e)

ProxyError: ('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

I have searched and searched for a solution to this problem and have tried a few different approaches without success. What am I doing wrong? (btw above was done in Spyder/IPython)

Bonus question.. how do you obtain a session cookie in Python? Help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: disable proxy then try again.   like:  your_proxies = {
      "http": None,
      "https": None,
    };result = requests.get(url='http://test.com/', proxies= your_proxies, headers=headers, data=payload);

Comment: You can get the answer for how to obtain a session cookie. [Python Requests Cookies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies)

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should be caused by failed at proxy auth.

Two solutions to solve this:

1. **Trying to contact your network administrator to get auth method** (like NTLM, Basic Auth, Digest etc) and username and password.
   As I know, Python Requests doesn't support NTLM. So if NTLM, you have no way for proxy auth.

If Basic Auth, pass your proxy to requests.get/post like below:

```
proxies = {
  "http": 'http://user:password@proxy.com/',
  "https": 'https://user:password@proxy.com/',
}
response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

You can refer [The Official Website of Python Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#digest-authentication) about how to auth for other methods.

2. **Another solution is ignore OS proxy setting.(but the request may be blocked when access external network resource because the security policy in your company)** There are two ways to implement this (session.trust_env=false; or your_proxy={'http':none,'https:':none'}.

The codes will be like:

```
import requests
url = "http://test:180/test.aspx"
session = requests.Session()
session.trust_env = False #disable OS proxy
headers = {}

response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)

#use empty proxy instead
proxies = {
  "http": None,
  "https": None,
}
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('test', 'test'), proxies=proxies)
print (response)
```